# References-Bibliography not showing up after compiling

Tags: bibliographies, springer

This is What my sn-article.tex file looks like(towards the end)

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here is what my sn-bibliography.bib file looks like

```
@article{bib1,
  title={Aspect-Level Sentiment Analysis on E-Commerce Data},
  author={S. Josephine Vanaja and Meena Belwal},
  journal={2018 International Conference on Inventive Research in Computing Applications (ICIRCA)},
  year={2018},
  pages={1275-1279}
}

@article{bib2,  
    author={Kiran, M. Vamsee Krishna and Vinodhini, R. E. and Archanaa, R. and Vimalkumar, K.},  
    booktitle={2017 4th International Conference on Advanced Computing and Communication Systems (ICACCS)},   
    title={User specific product recommendation and rating system by performing sentiment analysis on product reviews},   
    year={2017},  
    volume={},  
    number={},  
    pages={1-5},  
    doi={10.1109/ICACCS.2017.8014640}
    }

@article{bib3,
  author        = {R. G. Devi, Veena, P. V., Dr. M. Anand Kumar, and Dr. Soman K. P.},
  title         = "AMRITA-CEN@FIRE 2016: Code-mix entity extraction for Hindi-English and Tamil-English tweets",
  journal       = "CEUR Workshop Proceedings",
  volume        = "1737",
  number        = "",
  pages         = "304--308",
  year          = "2016"
}

@article{bib4,
author = {B., Premjith and Kp, Soman and Poornachandran, Prabaharan},
year = {2020},
month = {01},
pages = {},
title = {Amrita CEN@FACT: Factuality Identification in Spanish Text}
}

@article{bib5,
title = {Detection of Hate Speech Text in Hindi-English Code-mixed Data},
journal = {Procedia Computer Science},
volume = {171},
pages = {737-744},
year = {2020},
note = {Third International Conference on Computing and Network Communications (CoCoNet'19)},
issn = {1877-0509},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.procs.2020.04.080},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050920310498},
author = {K Sreelakshmi and B Premjith and K.P. Soman}
}

@article{bib6,
author = {Jha, Vikas and Poroli, Hrudya and N, Vinu and Vijayan, Vishnu and P, Prabaharan},
year = {2020},
month = {01},
pages = {2324-2333},
title = {DHOT-Repository and Classification of Offensive Tweets in the Hindi Language},
volume = {171},
journal = {Procedia Computer Science},
doi = {10.1016/j.procs.2020.04.252}
}

@article{bib7,
author = {Parekh, Pooja and Patel, Hetal},
year = {2017},
month = {05},
pages = {},
title = {Toxic Comment Tools: A Case Study},
doi = {10.26483/ijarcs.v8i5.3506}
}

@misc{bib8,
title="Perspective API",
url={https://www.perspectiveapi.com}
}

@misc{bib9,
title="Developers Perspective API",
url={https://developers.perspectiveapi.com/s/}
}

@@misc{bib10,
  doi = {10.48550/ARXIV.1702.08138},
  
  url = {https://developers.perspectiveapi v.com/},
  
  author = {Hosseini, Hossein and Kannan, Sreeram and Zhang, Baosen and Poovendran, Radha},
  
  keywords = {Machine Learning (cs.LG), Computers and Society (cs.CY), Social and Information Networks (cs.SI), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
  
  title = {Deceiving Google's Perspective API Built for Detecting Toxic Comments},
  
  publisher = {arXiv},
  
  year = {2017},
  
  copyright = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license}
}


@softmisc{bib11,
author = {Vaidya, Ameya and Mai, Feng and Ning, Yue},
year = {2019},
month = {09},
pages = {},
title = {Empirical Analysis of Multi-Task Learning for Reducing Model Bias in Toxic Comment Detection}
}

@softmisc{bib12,
author = {Mozafari, Marzieh and Farahbakhsh, Reza and Crespi, Noel},
year = {2019},
month = {12},
pages = {},
title = {A BERT-Based Transfer Learning Approach for Hate Speech Detection in Online Social Media}
}


@softmisc{bib13,
author = {Razavi, Amir H. and Inkpen, Diana and Uritsky, Sasha and Matwin, Stan},
title = {Offensive Language Detection Using Multi-Level Classification},
year = {2010},
publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
address = {Berlin, Heidelberg},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-13059-5_5},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-13059-5_5},
pages = {16–27},
series = {AI'10}
}

@softmisc{bib14,
author = {Djuric, Nemanja and Zhou, Jing and Morris, Robin and Grbovic, Mihajlo and Radosavljevic, Vladan and Bhamidipati, Narayan},
year = {2015},
month = {05},
pages = {29-30},
title = {Hate Speech Detection with Comment Embeddings},
doi = {10.1145/2740908.2742760}
}

@softmisc{bib15,
author = {Chen, Ying and Zhou, Yilu and Zhu, Sencun and Xu, Heng},
year = {2012},
month = {09},
pages = {71-80},
title = {Detecting Offensive Language in Social Media to Protect Adolescent Online Safety},
isbn = {978-1-4673-5638-1},
doi = {10.1109/SocialCom-PASSAT.2012.55}
}
```

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong? because nothing shows up after compiling.
[image]

Comment: what does the .blg file say?

Comment: You should also include your MWE. Otherwise we are just doing error guessing. It now could be as simple as not use `\cite{foo}` in the whole .tex file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't see any .blg file? I'm using OverLeaf, I see only tex, bib, bst, cls, eps files

Comment: look under the log-files.